# Dual Boot Windows 10 Pro Advice for 2021

Tags: windows-10, security, multi-boot, gaming

My long-time Macbook which I used as a development and business workstation just died on me and I cannot afford to replace it just now. I have a pretty decent windows gaming system that I would like to dual-use for a while but I need to lock it down and partition it's gaming and business functionality pretty tightly.

[NOTE]
If this is the wrong place to post this, or there is a better place, please let me know. Other relevant post were old and had little-to-no community input.

What I am considering is dual booting two separate windows 10 pro licenses, using TPM/Bitlocker with the business in the front, and a largely open sandbox install as the party in the back.

I'm no seasoned certified windows admin, but I know my way around pretty well and my bing-fu isn't atrocious, but what I'm looking for is any input from people who may have set up the same or similar and succeeded (or failed) on whether this is even a viable approach before I spend 10-100 hours mucking about with it.

What I have to work with:

```
- 1 Windows 10 Pro Retail License
- 1 Windows 10 Pro Upgrade License from:
    ○ 1 Windows XP Pro Retail License
    ○ 1 Windows 7 Pro Upgrade Retail License
- AMD Ryzen 5 3600 (Virtual TPM)
- 2 NVME Drives
- A couple low-wear HDD Drives
```

What I am anticipating it to look like and what I'll use it for:

```
Systems:
- 
  SystemName: "The Brain"
  Purpose: "Business, Development and Secure Correspondence"
  CoreTech: "WSL2, Git, Office, VSCode, GPG, SSL, Teams, Figma"
  Users: "Me"
- 
  SystemName: "Pinky"
  Purpose: "Gaming, Modding Games, 3D/2D Art, Running Sus Apps"
  CoreTech: "Bethesda Games, Paradox Games, Krita, Inkscape, Narf!"
  Users: "Me, Fiancée, Drunken Me"

Drives:
-
  DriveName: "NVME1"
  Size: ">475GB"
  Partitions:
  -
    VolumeName: "System - The Brain (C:)"
    Size: "125GB"
    Use: "Windows Applications, Settings, User Root"
    BitLocker: True
  -
    VolumeName: "Data - The Brain (D:)"
    Size: "200GB"
    Use: "User Documents, OneDrive"
    Bitlocker: True
  -
    VolumeName: "System - Pinky (C:)"
    Size: "125GB"
    Use: "Windows Applications, Settings, User Root"
    BitLocker: False

  Notes:
  - "Leaves 25GB+ for Boot and Recovery partitions"
    
-
  DriveName: "NVME2"
  Size: ">950GB"
  Partitions:
  -
    VolumeName: "Data - Pinky (D:)"
    Size: ">200GB"
    Use: "User Documents, Save Files, Dropbox, OneDrive"
    BitLocker: False
  -
    VolumeName: "Games - Pinky (G:)"
    Size: "750GB"
    Use: "Active Games, Active Mods"
    BitLocker: False

-
  DriveName: "HDD1"
  Size: ">475GB"
  Partitions:
  -
    VolumeName: "Archive - The Brain (A:)"
    Size: ">475GB"
    Use: "Local Project Archive, Local Library Archive"
    BitLocker: True


-
  DriveName: "HDD2"
  Size: ">475GB"
  Partitions:
  -
    VolumeName: "Archive - Pinky (A:)"
    Size: ">475GB"
    Use: "Archived Games, Archived Mods, Reference Photos/Videos"
    BitLocker: False
```

I have some other HDDs and maybe a SSD or two should I need them.

---

Any thoughts on best practices to go about this?

Is there a visual bootloader I could use instead use f8/msconfig to swap between them (ala apple bootcamp)?

Can I shield The Brain's filesystem completely from Pinky? Everything will be backed up on premises and through a few cloud machinations, but I'd love a way to lock down completely.

I won't really be running suspect applications - but some of the tools used in the modding community aren't exactly easily auditable or in anyway verified as entirely on the up-and-up. I'll use a proper container or vm instance if I'm genuinely doing something Narf!

I know I shouldn't $h*t where I eat, but for now this is what I have to do.

Appreciate any constructive thoughts or guidance, and if I've left anything out let me know.

Comment: I think if you just reinstall windows next to the old one, and not enter a key, you get it activated. Microsoft doesn't really care for anyone to use a license multiple times on the same computer as long as it is only being used once at a time. A dual boot situation would do that, so technically you are fine to use your license and install windows twice. The same license inside a VM is not okay though because then you run 2 instances of windows at the same time. (also, yes this comment was not meant to answer your question)

Comment: First, this isn't a bad post, except that it's very much asking for suggestions and opinions, and has many different questions inside it. Superuser is a Question and Answer site, so each post needs to have a single specific question that can have a single authoritatively correct answer. Other sites, such as forums, will handle open-ended and broad explorations like yours far better. If you can boil this down to a single question please do so. Also, having multiple questions isn't a problem here: just clearly delineate each individual question, and give each of them their own post.

Comment: A few notes, beyond my previous instructional comment: The OS can (nearly) always access all of the hardware connected to it. Preventing one OS from seeing other drives/partitions on the system, especially when they are compatible formats, is nearly impossible. Even if you set permissions just so on Pinky, The Brain can easily overrule those permissions to scan and the drives. A lot depends on what sort of local device management your business does on your computer. If your business is your own contract work, it's less of a concern, just keep things separate.